# Why are developers still using proprietary third-party libraries?

Tags: libraries, third-party-libraries, proprietary

As the open source world is fairly advanced now and you can find an open source  implementation of pretty much everything, why are people/developers still using the obscure/proprietary libraries? In what case these are absolutely needed?

Comment: see [On discussions and why they don't make good questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6742/31260)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Three obvious reasons:

1. There's no open source equivalent,
2. The company wants paid-for support that they can rely on.
3. They are a bit behind the times and do not yet trust open source libraries.

Comment: 4. their customer mandates use of a particular tech

Comment: 5. The only open source equivalent is GPL licensed and the company is unwilling to open up their own code.

Comment: 6. The choice was made in the past, long before anything remotely useful was available as open source, and it would be a risky, costly waste of time and resources to open up the application and link it to something different.

Comment: 7. The proprietary version is simply better

Comment: And, if you to work for a company that is so large that other companies are formed just to figure out new ways to sue you, then you may run into push-back from your own legal department.  Getting their approval to use open-source code might cost your team more than it costs to license a commercial version or even, to just write the ****ed thing from scratch.

Comment: 4 - The proprietary library is better.  Other than reason 1, I think this is next most obvious reason.